# Why cant I see image calls in a fiddler

Tags: image, href, fiddler

For example if we visit cnn.com and pick the cnn logo at bottom left screen.

URL : http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/footer/pngs/footer_cnn_logo.png.

Directly browse work is see the image. But if loading the page and seeing it through a fiddler don't see the call being made.

View Source of the page show's this :

div img src=http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/footer/pngs/footer_cnn_logo.png

Can some explain me the concept how this image gets delivered.

Answer (score 0):

The image was almost certainly in the cache. Hit CTRL+F5 in the browser (or hit CTRL+SHIFT+Delete in the browser to clear its cache).

In Fiddler, click Help > Troubleshoot Filters to ensure that Fiddler is not filtering anything out based on your settings.